# Why are arithmetical expressions not optimized for multiplication by 0 in C#

Tags: c#, programming-languages, expression, compiler-optimization

In order to evaluate a multiplication you have to evaluate the first term, then the second term and finally multiply the two values.

Given that every number multiplied by 0 is 0, if the evaluation of the first term returns 0 I would expect that the entire multiplication is evaluated to 0 without evaluating the second term.

However if you try this code:

```
var x = 0 * ComplexOperation();
```

The function ComplexOperation is called despite the fact that we know that x is 0.

The optimized behavior would be also consistent with the Boolean Operator '&&' that evaluates the second term only if the first one is evaluated as true. (The '&' operator evaluates both terms in any case)

I tested this behavior in `C#` but I guess it is the same for almost all languages.

Comment: Did you try this for int, since NAN is only defined for floating point numbers in .NET?

Comment: ComplexOperation is evaluated also for int

Comment: Should we have a `**` operator, I don't want an operator that short circuits unless I'm expecting it. You'll note, I can still use `&` if I choose.

Comment: @Jodrell as Oli said it cannot be done because my assertion is not true for floating point operations. It is true only for int so the ** operator would be applicable only to int

Comment: @Roberto and `byte`, `short`, `long`, `decimal`, etc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly, for floating-point, your assertion isn't even true!  Consider that `0 * inf` is not 0, and `0 * nan` is not 0.

But more generally, if you're talking about **optimizations**, then I guess the compiler is free to not evaluate `ComplexOperation` if it can prove there are no side-effects.

However, I think you're really talking about **short-circuit semantics** (i.e. a language feature, not a compiler feature).  If so, then the real justification is that C# is copying the semantics of earlier languages (originally C) to maintain consistency.

Comment: what does `0 * inf` evaluate to?

Comment: @Oli Suppose function is `int`. There is no option for `inf` then.

Comment: @SuzanCioc: Of course.  But would you really want a language where short-circuit semantics were defined for int, but not float?

Comment: I tested it, `0 * double.PositiveInfinity` == `double.NaN`

Comment: @Oli depends on. I guess I would expect such optimization if `C#` was able to declare function as having no side effects.

Comment: @SuzanCioc: An optimization is one thing (and this may well happen, I don't know).  But short-circuit **semantics** are another thing entirely.

Comment: @Oli optimizer SHOULD NOT remove function call even if `0 * inf` would be `0`. Imagine `var x = 0 * CloseTheWindowAndReturnItsSize();` Optimizer can't remove closing a window.

Comment: @SuzanCioc: Yes, I'm well-aware of that ;)

Comment: @Oli I would expect that the language offers a ** short circuit multiplication. However since 0 * inf and 0 * nan gives results different than 0 it cannot be short circuited for float numbers (and consistently also for int)

Comment: The question highlights the potential benefits of functional programming. Its all positive till you get to IO.

Answer (score 6):

C# is not functional, so functions can have side effects. For example, you can print something from inside `ComlpexOperation` or change global static variables. So, whether it is called is defined by `*` contract.

You found yourself an example of different contracts with `&` and `&&`.

Answer (score 3):

The language defines which operators have short-circuit semantics and which do not. Your `ComplexOperation` function may have side effects, those side effects may be deliberate, and the compiler is not free to assume that they should not occur just because the result of the function is effectively not used.

Comment: But I guess the question is why the language doesn't define short-circuit semantics for arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 2):

I will also add this would be obfuscated language design.  There would be oodles of SO questions to the effect of...

```
//why is foo only called 9 times?????????
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    print((i-5)*foo());
}
```

Why allow short-circuiting booleans and not short-circuiting `0*`?  Well, firstly I will say that mixing short-circuit boolean with side-effects is a common source of bugs in code - if used well among maintainers who understand it as an obvious pattern then it may be okay, but it's very hard for me to imagine programmers becoming at all used to a hole in the integers at 0.